# Python Flask can't host Backend on my machine

Tags: python, flask, hosting, fritzbox

So I wanted to host my backed on my machine for my website.
The Problem is I can't the frontend works perfectly but the Flask backend doesn't.
The backend works when I use localhost or my local ip to access it.
But doesn't work when I try to use it with the link :
https://desktop-1234567.1234567890qwert.myfritz.net:3182
(this one is fake)
It displays this error message :
[image: Cant find it]
So basically it says that it can't find the backend the Flask backend also dosen't react.
Even though I port forwarded the port 3182 with my-Fritz :
[image: I port forwarded it]
I also turned off Windows Firewall and it dosen't help

My Fritz is basically a free service from [avm](https://en.avm.de) for Firtz-Box users (that's my Router) 
It generates a sub domain where all your traffic is routed through this is useful since this url is static.

I tried it with a simpler backend :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "<h1>Test</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        debug=False,
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=3182,
        threaded=True
    )
```

and it also doesn't work it gives the same error message as above.
I also tried using waitress to host this simple app but it also won't work.

It has to be Flask since I can access my Frontend with the link on port 80 and 443.

I'm on Windows 10 and I hope somebody knows why this isn't working.

So yeah pleas help me I searched and it appears that no one had this exact problem before (But you never know on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what the issue is.
The Issue is that I used `"0.0.0.0"` as the host parameter to run the app.
This tells flask to use IPV4, however I looked in to it and found out that "My Fritz" uses IPV6 so I just had to change the host parameter to use IPV6 by replacing `"0.0.0.0"` with `::`.

That's it hope it helps, if anyone runs into the same issue as me.